# After using File::makeDirectory in Laravel, I get "mkdir(): No such file or directory" error

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to create a folder that will contain all images of an image album. Unfortunately, when I try to use File::makeDirectory I get the "mkdir(): No such file or directory" error. Now, I am either using it incorrectly or there's something wrong with my path. My goal is to create a folder called $albumName in my albums folder. Also considering I'm using php artisan storage:link, should my path be:

```
public/albums/'.$albumName
```

or

```
public/storage/albums/'.$albumName
```

My code so far.

```
public function uploadAlbum(Request $request){

        $albumName = $request['albumName'];
        $albumPath = File::makeDirectory('public/albums/'.$albumName);


        return redirect()->route('home');
    }
```

the error

C:\MAMP\htdocs\LaravelProject\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem.php

```
        return $directories;
    }

    /**
     * Create a directory.
     *
     * @param  string  $path
     * @param  int     $mode
     * @param  bool    $recursive
     * @param  bool    $force
     * @return bool
     */
    public function makeDirectory($path, $mode = 0755, $recursive = false, $force = false)
    {
        if ($force) {
            return @mkdir($path, $mode, $recursive);
        }

        return mkdir($path, $mode, $recursive);
    }

    /**
     * Move a directory.
     *
     * @param  string  $from
     * @param  string  $to
     * @param  bool  $overwrite
     * @return bool
     */
    public function moveDirectory($from, $to, $overwrite = false)
    {
        if ($overwrite && $this->isDirectory($to)) {
            if (! $this->deleteDirectory($to)) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return @rename($from, $to) === true;
    }
Arguments
"mkdir(): No such file or directory"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass full path to the directory:

```
File::makeDirectory(storage_path('public/app/albums/' . $albumName));
```

Comment: @Bobimaru you should use the real path. I've updated the code with another example. Try it. Also, the error is not helpful here,  please show results of `dd(storage_path('public/app/albums/' . $albumName))`. But before that make sure you're using the right directory.